# Will DOM reconstructs after partial view is loaded via ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Div is filled using ajax call which returns a partial view . In this case,Do DOM will be reconstructed ? . Since ,I have some javascripts preloaded which will handle client side events of that partial view .Do I need to attach event handler using live event or On event  (jquery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ajax calls will load the partial views without reconstructing the entire page.  Just make sure you aren't firing the click events off of a submit button (unless you are preventing the default to stop the post back).  Since the partial is loaded after the page has loaded you need to keep your script in the main page but tie the events to the document instead of the selector.  something like

```
$(document).on('click', '.classSelector', function(){
    //your code here
});
```

a click event defined in this way will trigger off of items on your partial